# Program crash on file output c++

Tags: c++, stream, char, ifstream

My program crashes unexpectedly when I try and output my results to a `.txt` file.

Basically, I want to store a list of students in a `.txt` file and retrieve them for later convenience. My program can store the values as variables, however the moment you want to save them to the output file, the program itself crashes.

This is my code

```
//STUDENTS CLASS

char** studentNames;
int numberOfNames;

void Students::setNumberOfNames(int namenumbers) // Takes in the number of student names to store
{
    numberOfNames = namenumbers;
}


void Students::setStudentNames() // Takes a number of student names and stores them.
{
    char studentinput[128]
    studentNames = new char*[numberOfNames];
    for (int i=0; i<=numberOfNames; i++)
    {
        studentNames[i] = new char[128];
        cout << "Student " << i << ": " << "\n";
        cin.getline(studentinput, sizeof(studentinput));
        strcpy(studentNames[i], studentinput);
    }
}


//MAIN CLASS
Student s;
int nums;
int main()
{
    cout << "How many names would you like to store? " << endl;
    cin >> nums;
    s.setNumberOfNames(nums):
    s.setStudentNames();
    for(int i=0; i<=s.numberOfNames; i++)
    {
        cout << s.numberOfNames [i] << "\n"; // THIS WORKS FINE! DOES WHAT I SAY :)
    }

    // THIS IS WHERE IT CRASHES. I TRY AND STORE THE NAMES INTO THE `.txt` FILE.
    //IF YOU WANT TO STORE 3 NAMES, IT WORKS FINE, BUT IF YOU WANT TO STORE LIKE
    //12 NAMES THE WHOLE THING CRASHES. WHEN I COMMENT OUT THE BOTTOM BLOCK
    //OF CODE THE PROGRAM WORKS FINE, BUT I WANT TO STORE THE NAMES.

    ofstream outputFiles ("example.txt");
    if(outputFiles.is_open())
    {
        for(int i=0; i<=s.numberOfNames; i++)
        {
            outputFiles << s.studentNames [i] << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show declaration of Student.  What does "crash" mean?  Please show SPECIFIC errors.  Time to to lean how to use the debugger also.

Comment: Chances are your life will be a lot easier if you use `std::string` here.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
for (int i=0; i<=numberOfNames; i++)
```

to

```
for (int i=0; i < numberOfNames; i++)
```

everywhere in your program.

Comment: This still crashes the program I believe the ofstream is the cause

Comment: @RewsProg I suggest you first follow OldProgrammer's advice in the comments.